# C# Strategy to set up desktop app to query remote server

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a .NET desktop app that will be deployed to clients' machines, and I am considering how to license it. My preferred strategy is to code something in the app that sends a query to a file or database on a remote server to see if the user (identified by, say, email and password) has a current licence. The response need only be one byte, for "yes, you have a current licence" or "no, you don't", or some such.

What's the best way to do this?

My first and worst thought was to set up an XML file on the remote server, and query that via ftp. But, that could expose the site and the file to hacking.

A better strategy seems to be to set up a SQL database on the server, and code the app to query it in a read-only capacity.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Apologies for the non-specificness of this question. I'll have a clearer idea of what I'm looking for when I find it.

Comment: Honestly, I find that setting up an SQL database, and using MySQL to get the information would be the best option.

Comment: The problem with that is, if you have a connection string or something stored in the app...how will that prevent just querying the database himself for all registered users? You may have an extra layer of encryption but you wouldn't want to show the table, still.

Comment: Agreed - the chances of a bona fide client hacking the code are remote, but that's no excuse for writing vulnerable code. In any case, I'll be deploying to corporate environments, and I would not wish to invoke the wrath of their IT departments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what others would do, but what I would do is use a [WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) on a server to expose only an Authentication `[OperationContract]` for the client (your app),  or use a [custom UsernamePasswordValidator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59927/WCF-Service-over-HTTPS-with-custom-username-and-pa). Then I would do the actual database querying on the server-side validation so the only thing exposed to the user is the `[OperationContract]`.

Comment: Thanks Tyress - I'm reading about WCF and it appears to be what I'm looking for. The MSDN site even has a walkthrough with Visual Studio - so, it speaks my language. I'll work through this and figure out some unit tests.

Comment: No prob! I'm glad it's what you're looking for.